# Are there any good programming environments/IDEs for Windows Mobile devices?

Tags: windows-mobile, development-environment

By this, I don't mean PC-based development environments (like Visual Studio) for developing and deploying Windows Mobile applications.  Rather, I mean an IDE that runs on Windows Mobile devices and lets you write and test code there.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Over the past year or so I have been searching regularly for new developer tools for use on Windows Mobile based devices and have come across many. I currently have installed on my device [PythonCE](http://pythonce.sourceforge.net/), [eTcl](http://www.evolane.com/software/etcl/index.html), [dsForth](http://www.delosoft.com/), [PocketLogo](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pocketlogo/) (The documents which comes with it is in German though), [Rebol](http://www.rebol.com/platforms-core.html), and [Pocket Scheme](http://www.mazama.net/scheme/pscheme.htm).

Development tools which I have heard about but not tried are [Pocket GCC](http://pocketgcc.sourceforge.net/index.html), [PocketC](http://www.orbworks.com/), [Lua](http://lua-users.org/wiki/LuaDistributions), [J](http://www.jsoftware.com/), [Pocket Programming Language](http://www.arianesoft.ca/page.php?1) and [Pocket C#](http://pocketgcc.sourceforge.net/pcsharp/)

A good website to find other interpreters is [www.rainer-keuchel.de](http://www.rainer-keuchel.de/), unfortunately though it seems the author has been inactive for quite sometime.

[Here is a link to a thread on on mobilitysite.com with some useful findings.](http://www.mobilitysite.com/boards/business-development/92214-programming-pocket-pc-entirely-ppc-not-desktop-based-solutions.html#post772986)

If I find anything new I'll come back and update.

Comment: Wow, quite a collection. Which one do you like best so far?

Comment: eTcl partly because I like the Tcl language and building GUIs isn't bad at all. PythonCE and Tkinter if you are working with older devices, but I think you could have the QT windowing toolkit configured somehow which would provide the look and feel for modern devices.

Answer (score 3):

I know of no such thing, and I doubt it would be a good idea; as such I don't think any such thing exists.

It would be a cool project for you to write though, I can't imagine it would be that hard. You would just need a compiler that runs on the WM platform.

Wait; I found this:

http://www.freewarepocketpc.net/ppc-download-c-ide-mobile-v9-0.html

Comment: Perfect! Thanks for the link. And it makes a great counterpoint to your first sentence!  :)

Answer (score 1):

You could try Basic4PPC (www.basic4ppc.com).

It's a great programming-enviroment (based on the NET framework) with a very active and numerous user-community. There is also a version of the IDE which can be used on the device.

Rgds,
Moster67