# Coding Using Mobile Phone

Tags: mobile-phones

I am wondering is there any mobile phone available in this world that enable us to compile or interpret any code we type in?

Let say I want to code a simple program like in http://projecteuler.net, and I cannot find any computer nearby. I really want to code while going home using public transportation or waiting the bus, using my mobile phone.

The keypad will not be an issue, since QWERTY is good enough to type the code. The language could be pascal, php, or other lightweight language.

The IDE doesn't have to be sophisticated, text editor will do.

Comment: The google phone used to let you, but that was a buggy insecure telnet implementation ;)

Comment: See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/275436/are-there-any-good-programming-environments-ides-for-windows-mobile-devices).

Comment: Have you a particular phone or operating system in mind?

Comment: @Andrew: currently I live in Indonesia, and google phone is something that not easy to get in the market.

@Rowland: Symbian in NOKIA Phone, I prefer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are lots of Python interpreters available for mobile devices. Check out [Python for Mobile Devices](http://www.awaretek.com/pymo.html) for starters.

Answer (score 4):

I would suggest that you buy a lightweight netbook and carry it around.

Comment: That's already in my mind, but I just curious whether there exist such phones. I heard friend of mine (from his wife, just several minutes ago) that he uses Nokia N73 and using Python.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should check out [python for s60](http://opensource.nokia.com/projects/pythonfors60/)

Answer (score 1):

I normally use MidpSSH (JAVA SSH client for mobile phones) and connect to my box at home through GPRS. That way you have access to everything your server has.

Answer (score 1):

http://codepad.org works great even on any mobile browser.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [MacinCloud](http://www.macincloud.com/). Your mobile device can become a Mac, so you will be able to run developing programs, such as python or Xcode, with your phone.

Answer (score 0):

I once saw a HTML editor for Symbian S60 devices
And also I used putty tool for telnet on Symbian S60

Answer (score 0):

If you use one of the OpenMoko ones, you potentially have a
fully fledged linux at your disposal and you can do 
everything just as on an resource limited desktop.

Don't know if the sell any with usable keyboard though.

Addit:
This reminds me of the days of my zaurus, when I had
a full MySQL server, webserver and ssh running on it.

That thing kicked some serious ass compared to limited
PocketWindowsCE stuff. Unfortunately it got it's ass
seriously kicked in terms of PIM functionality, but the geek
factor was well worth it :)

Answer (score 0):

I just text it to myself through email and then compile it later. :-)