# Programming on (not *for*) an Android device

Tags: android, mobile

Are there any interpreters available for the Android platform for any language at all? If so, do they work with both physical and on-screen keyboards?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you can use android scripting engine and play with python and other languages on the device. An article¹ seems to confirm that (with a screenshot of a huge "Edit" button ;-))

¹ http://www.linux-mag.com/id/7370/

Comment: Yes, excellent. This is going to make my commute much more bearable.

Answer (score 4):

RFO BASIC! is availble. It is a very full featured basic and can even compile into stand alone code.
Availble for free in Android market

http://www.laughton.com/basic/

Answer (score 0):

You can use Frink. A "simple" oo language which is mostly used as "calculator" with units or unit conversions. See: http://futureboy.us/frinkdocs/android.html